# My ipython terminal cannot start, got an import error

Tags: python, ipython

I can't get my `ipython` terminal to start.
I got an import error

This is the error I get when trying to run `ipython`:

```
C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop>ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\ipython.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 14, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class, line_magic
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import oinspect
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygments\formatters\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pygments.formatters._mapping import FORMATTERS
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygments\formatters\_mapping.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pygments.formatters.rtf import RtfFormatter
  File "c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygments\formatters\rtf.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pygments.util import get_int_opt, surrogatepair
ImportError: cannot import name 'surrogatepair' from 'pygments.util' (c:\users\emmanuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygments\util.py)
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are likely using an old version of `Pygments`. The current version implements the method that the error is complaining about- you can see that [here](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/master/pygments/util.py).

Try upgrading the package by doing

```
pip install [package_name] --upgrade
```

More details on alternative installions are [here](https://github.com/pygments/pygments#installing)